# Reply link in email body

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, mailto

I need create in e-mail link to reply. When I press this link, I need that open a reply letter whith custom body, got into chain of letters.

I tryed use that:

```html
<a href="mailtoadmin@mail.com?subject=Re: subject&body=custom body" target="_parent">mail to me in parent</a>
```

but this create a new letter, not reply.

When I press "reply" in letter and send new letter, it has keys in the header "In-Reply-To" and "References" (link to original letter). When I write new letter, his don't have this keys.

Comment: Sorry, I meen that:<a href="mailto:admin@mail.com?subject=Re: subject&body=custom body" target="_parent">mail to me in parent</a>

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no direct possibility to reply to special emails but there is still the possibility to create a new email with "Re:".

Please note that you must use **"%20"** instead of spaces and **"%0A "** instead of Enter in the subject line and body. To create the text with "%20" and "%0A" you can use this page https://www.urlencoder.org/

**Try this** I hope it helps you.

```html
<a href="mailto:mailtoadmin@mail.com?subject=Re:%20Email%20Answer&body=Email%20Body%20Text">Try this</a>
```

However, in the case of an email that you send, you can enter these details:

Subject: Letter to invoice

Body: Dear ladies and gentlemen, please send me the invoice.

Then just put this text in the html code before you send the email.

```html
<a href="mailto:mailtoadmin@mail.com?subject=Re:%20Letter%20to%20invoice&body=%0A%0A%0ADear%20ladies%20and%20gentlemen%2C%0Aplease%20send%20me%20the%20invoice.">With answer text...</a>
```

Comment: It's not help. Most e-mail servers don't put letter into chain of letters if his not have keys  "In-Reply-To" and "References"

Comment: @Vozdr But it's not the only help I gave! One way to implement this is my second code proposal. It is more complicated but possible.

Comment: Your first and second variants are the same

Answer (score 0):

The mailto directive is a part of html with the primary task of telling the browser to tell the OS to create a new email in the default email application. When the directive is used in an email, the default behaviour of most email clients is to create a mew message.

Unfortunately there is no good way around this, and a replyto directive has not been implemented in html for good reasons.

Comment: May be has a bad way around this? =)

Comment: No reliable ones in my view. Sorry.